# jQuery validate get the error message below the textbox / input element

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/msbUM/
How do I get the error message below the textbox / input element?

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout

Comment: Should I be using labels to get it working through display: block; ? like it is done here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` to label.error:

```
label.error { 
   float: none; color: red; 
   padding-left: .5em;
   vertical-align: top; 
   display: block;
}​
```

Comment: should I be using labels and not tables for display:block to work?

Answer (score 7):

Apply `display:block` to the error labels.

Comment: should I be using labels and not tables for display:block to work?

Comment: Excellent, you have did a hundred lines of code job with a single line. Thats called excellence.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick solution can be to replace `label` as error element with `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#frmId").validate({
        errorElement:'div',
        rules: {
        // RULES //
        },
        messages: {
        // MESSAGES //
        } 
    });
});
```